# TYPO3 Adding form property custom errors from within Controller action

Tags: typo3

Previously it was possible to include custom form property errors from inside a controller action using this call:

```
$this->propertyMapper->getMappingResults()->addError($error,$propertyName);
```

However with the newest TYPO3 version, `$this->propertyMapper` has been set to private and cannot be accessed from own controller.

I have errors from Repository calculations and would like them included for certain properties.

1. Is there a way to include custom validation property errors from a controller action?
2. After errors are included, is it necessary to redirect to error action? If so, what would be the proper procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that one can use inside a controller action.

```
$result=new TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result();
$result->forProperty($this->request->getControllerActionName().'.'.$property)->addError($error);
$this->request->setOriginalRequestMappingResults($result);
```

Although the `$this->request->setOriginalRequestMappingResults()` method is discouraged with a note on the method for reasons of *immutability*, it's a good thing that its public and one can use it inside the controller action for the following reasons,

1. When execution finally make it into the action method, no errors from validation will be present and so no validation results will be there to mutate.
2. Even if for some reason there were, the `Result` object contains a public `merge()` method that one can use to safely merge the former with the later results.

> Note:

The `$error` variable is a new instance of `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Error`.
The `$property` variable on the other hand, is the name of the erroneous property within your domain model or DTO.

Comment: Where did you put this lines into? newAction()? createAction()? initializeCreateAction()?

Comment: @JKB For purposes of answering your question specifically, `initializeNewAction()`s would be best since `createAction()`s may send you to form (for example), whereas `initializeNewAction()`s have equal access to the same resources as `newAction()`s such as access o the same repository. However, in my implementation, I do it by utilizing the `addErrorFlashMessage` method (which, is meant to be overridden and for that purpose, and called after every action call.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using the "initialize***Action()" and doing the manual stuff there is:

```
public function initializeUpdateAction()
{
    $result = $this->arguments->getArgument('myArgument')->validate();
    $result->addError(new Error('Error', 12345));
}
```